# Dynamically add extra price on subtotal on cart

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, event-observer, shopping-cart-price-rules

I need your help in solving one of my issue related to adding extra/custom price on subtotal on cart page. I have called a observer for checkout_cart_product_add_after and sales_convert_quote_item_to_order_item event and in which I am trying to add dynamic price from below code

```
$item->setCustomPrice($price);
$item->setOriginalCustomPrice($price);
```

This is allow me add in unit Price but I want to add in Subtotal of product. Also I have to tried to add price via custom options but it adds in Additional_optional field and not stored in info_buyrequest so might it not reflect to the subtotal price.

Please advise for suggestion.

Thanks

Comment: Can you do it using promotions->shopping cart price rules? You can define your rule there to add your extra price.

Comment: No kishor! I want to add dynamically or product wise. So I need to do from observer.

Comment: Try mageworx multifee extension

Comment: Hey! Its paid extension and I want to done by programmatically I have create some dynamic custom options based on products and their price.

Comment: Yeah, not everything is free in live. But maybe we cannot make it for less than what that kind of module cost. So it is either some kind of (payed) module or default Magento. Or create your own module

Comment: That's why I am creating my own module, but just facing an issues listed above. If you have any idea to resolve then let me know

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplished this by overriding Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item via modules config.xml:

```
<global>
    <models>
        <sales>
            <rewrite>                    
            <quote_item>Namespace_Module_Model_Quote_Item</quote_item>
            </rewrite>
        </sales>
    </models>
</global>
```

And then overriding the calcRowTotal()

```
class Namespace_Module_Model_Quote_Item extends Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item
{
    protected $customRowTotalPrice = null;

    public function setCustomRowTotalPrice($price)
    {
        $this->customRowTotalPrice = $price;
    }

    public function calcRowTotal()
    {
        if ($this->customRowTotalPrice !== null) {
            $this->setRowTotal($this->getStore()->roundPrice($this->customRowTotalPrice));
            $this->setBaseRowTotal($this->getStore()->roundPrice($this->customRowTotalPrice));
            return $this;
        }

        $qty = $this->getTotalQty();
        $total = $this->getStore()->roundPrice($this->getCalculationPriceOriginal()) * $qty;
        $baseTotal = $this->getStore()->roundPrice($this->getBaseCalculationPriceOriginal()) * $qty;

        $this->setRowTotal($this->getStore()->roundPrice($total));
        $this->setBaseRowTotal($this->getStore()->roundPrice($baseTotal));
        return $this;
    }

}
```